# HERE Routing API v8 is a long way behind the documentation. When will it be finished?

Tags: here-api

I have been trying to calculate a route via POST according to this documentation:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html

The comment under the heading "Calculate routes via POST" says "At the moment, only select parameters are permitted in the POST payload. In particular, those parameters that due to request size may be limited in the query string."

Through trial an error (because it's not in the documentation) I have worked out these parameters are not accepted in the POST body:
transportMode,
return,
origin,
destination,
via.

Parameters that are accepted in the POST body (according to the error message) are:
avoid &
ev

I need to send via points in the POST body, because I want to use 1500 points which don't fit in the query string, but via it's not accepted.
Could via, origin & destination parameters please be added to POST body in the Routing API v8?

The Calculate route from a sequence of trace points currently in alpha would also be useful. How many years have these been waiting?

Comment: As for a particular route  calculation there will be only one   origin, destination, transportMode. Could you please elaborate your use-case, why you want these parameters in post body request?

Comment: The main parameter I want in the POST body is via, to avoid getting a http 414 error (URI too long). The maximum number of via points I can submit is about 280 - 290 depending on the browser (Safari can do 290), but I want 1500 via points or even more if possible.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the information. Could you please elaborate your use-case, why there is requirement for the 1500+ via?

Comment: The documentation at https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html                                says "Disclaimer: A route handle is not suitable for persistent route storage! It can be invalidated at any time."            To get around this problem we are saving the coordinate for every point along the route so that it can be recreated exactly as it was. We can't recalculate from just a few points because we have to know the route has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters that are accepted in the POST body are: avoid & ev
These parameters are not accepted in the POST body: transportMode, return, origin, destination, via.
Considering the performance of the system. The maximum number of via points we can submit is about 280 - 290 depending on the browser (Safari can do 290).